# HTML/CSS Footer starts at middle of page then moves to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, footer

I'm having an issue where my footer starts at the middle of my page and then moves to the bottom of the page. It's not an animation, it's more of the footer loads at the middle of the page (When it does this it is placed above any image or text I have cutting it off), disappears, then reappears at the bottom of the page where it is intended.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Dan Garofalo &copy; 2020
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What devices are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on my desktop. I've tested this in Chrome and Edge. The same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Dan Garofalo &copy; 2020
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm assuming my problem now is that something in my CSS file is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a missing  tag from an animation. I fixed my issue. Thanks to everyone who took time to try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `position: absolute` make sure that the footer's parent element is `<body>` tag. If your footer element ends up inside an element that is not body AND that element has a `position: relative` then your footer will be positioned within that element. Example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
```

In the above example, `.child` will be positioned within `.parent`.

To avoid this, it is better to use `position: fixed` for your footer. This will imply:

```css
.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
```